# Google script: How do I find active cell in a different spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have an active cell in an open google sheet. I have a macro in a different spreadsheet that wants to get the value of the target active cell in a different google spreadsheet. Currently when I run the macro it is finding Sheet1 in the target workbook, but not the active sheet. How do I find the active sheet and active cell when I run the macro?

```
function getFormula() {
  //Precedents
  var ssThis=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1VMwjomfjtJLIQc<replaced>8J1zWx_GujXuCY");
  //Universal Demo - v5
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Pev8gCbl_Mn9JMJId<replaced>Cbc0aikBZambI");
  var targetSheet=tss.getActiveSheet();
  var targetSheetName=targetSheet.getName();
  Logger.log(targetSheetName);
  var cellThis=targetSheet.getActiveCell();
  var targetFormula=cellThis.getFormula();
  Logger.log(targetFormula);
  getPrecedents(targetFormula);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The script doesn’t have a direct relation with the Sheets UI regarding the active cells, sheets, etc, at least that you’re using a container bound spreadsheet and you’re running the script with a macro or add-on inside the spreadsheets UI (as i understand you’re doing). But in this case, you’ll only be able to work with the active cells on the spreadsheet that’s container bound.

To summarize, the functions getActiveSheet() and getActiveCell() will only return  the correct value for a container bound spreadsheet, running the script inside the spreadsheet (macro or add-on) and using the “getActive...” functions to obtain the spreadsheet, sheet or range, (instead of openById()) [1]. For example:

```
var ssThis = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet=ssThis.getActiveSheet();
var cellThis=activeSheet.getCurrentCell();
```

In any other cases, on the spreadsheet you open, it will always return the first sheet and the first celL (A1). At least you use the “activate()” function [2] or “setActive…” functions [3] to set the active cell or sheet, but for this you would have to know the active cell.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setactiverangerange